# add_action('init') not work

Tags: login, actions, init

my code is

```
add_action('init', 'user_logged_in');
function user_logged_in(){
    if( is_user_logged_in() && is_page('login')){
    wp_redirect(home_url());
    exit;
    }
}
```

the page slug and name is "login"

I do not want the logged in member to access the login page.

But this code does not work in functions.php.

Can you tell me what went wrong?

Comment: I believe `init` is too early to determine `is_page()`. Try a later hook, like `template_redirect`.

Comment: @JacobPeattie
wow it work!
Thanks to you, I got to know a good hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `init` is too early to determine `is_page()`. Try a later hook, like `template_redirect`.

```
function wpse_344136_user_logged_in(){
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page( 'login' ) ){
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_344136_user_logged_in' );
```